# Rotate TEXT vertically in Email

Tags: html, html-email

I m in a situation where i need to set some text in vertical order in email body, like this

[image]

using following css i can set text vertically in HTML but not able to set same in GMAIL Email body.

**Code from my Gmail Body:**

```
<div style=" width:50px; float:left; position:relative;padding-top:80px;transform: rotate(-90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);"> 
    <h1 id="Header" style="direction: rtl;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal; color: #434242; white-space: nowrap; position:relative; height:auto; "> newsletter 1 </h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the full vertical-text code from the email body?

Comment: <div style=" width:50px; float:left; position:relative;padding-top:80px;transform: rotate(-90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);">
<h1 id="Header" style="direction: rtl;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal;
color: #434242;
white-space: nowrap; position:relative; height:auto; ">
newsletter 1
</h1>
</div>

Comment: Is Gmail the only email client you need to support? If you manage to get this working with Gmail I can imagine other email clients (such as Outlook) will have problems with this.

Comment: No , need to get it in all email clients..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use inline CSS with Gmail. try `style=""` on your elements

Edit: And of course you can not use all CSS attributes in Gmail. Here is a [list](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) that might be useful.

Comment: Edited answer, take a look

Comment: any alternate you suggest?

Comment: Not really. Remember that newsletter design is very different to website design. You need to ignore all usual standards, you need to use tables, inline styles, img tags etc. (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/8015670/655316)

Answer (score 1):

gmail doesnt support the style tag in body .
Do you have used style tag in body section ?

Comment: Actually it does but filters out most of the selectors and some unless you start them with *. The same thing about attributes - some of them are removed.