# Hotmail not showing html or css background

Tags: background, background-image, newsletter, hotmail

I had problems with backgrounds not showing in most E-Mail clients such as GMail or Yahoo Mail but I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015515/background-image-css-inside-an-html-email-gmail-does-not-support) and problem solved by replacing (although I lost some properties like background-repeat and position) `<table style="background: url('bg.png');">` to `<table background="bg.png">`.

But now I'm facing the same problem in **Hotmail** and none of the above form of codes seems to work.

[This page](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is the reference of answers to most similar questions in stackoverflow, and it says that Outlook.com (new hotmail) does not support css background and I should use `background` attribute instead, but mine is not working.

What I'm doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2):

Outlook only supports background in the body tag.

Two ways to go for email backgrounds:

Via VML: [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/)

or here is the less fancy way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/'); background-color: #252525; background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat; background-position: top left;" bgcolor="#252525">
<!-- BODY FAKE PANEL -->
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
<!-- CENTER FLOAT -->
      <table width="600" height="800" border="0" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
Center panel
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<!-- /CENTER FLOAT -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- /BODY FAKE PANEL -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure your fancy solution wont do what I want, because I'm using too many backgrounds for different elements (table, td, etc.) but I'll take a look at VML way, I hope it works...

Comment: My (less) fancy way only works for the entire email body. Up until the VML technique was discovered, there was no way to add background images to elements in Outlook.