# CSS not loaded on email template

Tags: html, css, email, multipart

Whatever reason it is, when I try to send my mailings my css is not loaded correctly. My email background is gone and the email template looks stripped. I tried to use inline CSS but also that was no luck for me. I tried to upload my images to another host to see if that's the reason. But no luck after all.

I have converted my web template to mail template. But still no luck...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<head></head>
<body style="background-image: url('http://s30.postimg.org/3zs80ks9t/image.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed; background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #5C5959; width: 100%; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.06em;" bgcolor="#5C5959">
<div style="width: 1000px; min-height: 1000px; text-align: center; color: #595959; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" align="center">
<div style="color: white; float: left; margin-left: 55px; margin-top: 40px;"><a href="http://haptotherapiemris.nl" title="Home" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo.png" border="0"></a></div>      
<div style="color: white;"><div style="color: white;"></div></div>
<div style="color: white; clear: both; height: 50px;"></div>
<div style="color: white; clear: both; text-align: center; width: 1000px; height: 38px; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red-up.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="center"></div>
<div style="color: white; text-align: center; width: 1000px; margin-top: -2px9; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="center">
<div style="color: white; text-align: left; width: 760px; height: auto; background-color: transparent; margin: -15px 120px -8px;" align="left">
<h1 style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 19px; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff;">Titel</h1>
<br>content
</div>
</div>
<div style="color: white; text-align: right; width: 1000px; height: 74px; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red-down.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="right"></div>          
<div style="color: white;">
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/HaptotherapieMichaelRis" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-fb.png"></a>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/#!/Info_MichaelRis" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://blog.haptotherapiemris.nl/" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-blog.png"></a>
</div>
<div style="color: white;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<head></head>
<body style="background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg.jpg'); background-attachment: fixed; background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #5C5959; width: 100%; font-variant: normal; font-style: normal; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.06em;" bgcolor="#5C5959">
<style type="text/css">
h1 a:hover { color: #5e5e5e !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
.veolay-menu ul li.menuitem a:hover { color: #c20016 !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: #ffffff !important; height: 47px !important; }
.menusub ul li.menuitem a:hover { color: #c20016 !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: #ffffff !important; background: transparent url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/menubalksub-hover.png') repeat-x center top !important; }
.menusub ul li.menuitemactief a:hover { color: #c20016 !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: #ffffff !important; background: transparent url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/menubalksub-hover.png') repeat-x center top !important; }
></style>
<div style="width: 1000px; min-height: 1000px; text-align: center; color: #595959; background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;" align="center">
<div style="color: white; float: left; margin-left: 55px; margin-top: 40px;"><a href="http://haptotherapiemris.nl" title="Home" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo.png" border="0"></a></div>      
<div style="color: white;"><div style="color: white;"></div></div>
<div style="color: white; clear: both; height: 50px;"></div>
<div style="color: white; clear: both; text-align: center; width: 1000px; height: 38px; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red-up.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="center"></div>
<div style="color: white; text-align: center; width: 1000px; margin-top: -2px\9; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red.png'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="center">
<div style="color: white; text-align: left; width: 760px; height: auto; background-color: transparent; margin: -15px 120px -8px;" align="left">
<h1 style="font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 19px; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff;">Titel</h1>
<br>content
</div>
</div>
<div style="color: white; text-align: right; width: 1000px; height: 74px; background-image: url('http://nieuwsbrief.michaelris.nl/files/images/bg-red-down.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-position: center top;" align="right"></div>          
<div style="color: white;">
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/HaptotherapieMichaelRis" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-fb.png"></a>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/#!/Info_MichaelRis" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://blog.haptotherapiemris.nl/" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;"><img border="0" src="http://haptotherapiemris.nl/images/logo-blog.png"></a>
</div>
<div style="color: white;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that all your images are public references on the web? So in other words if I paste any of your image link into my browser I will be able to see the image?

Comment: `background-image` is not supported by most email clients. I would hand code this with tables and inline css, using only supported css statements.

Comment: you should go back to ancient coding style and code the newsletter entirely in tables. using css is a pain in the ass for email templates.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an HTML newsletter?

If so, then i'm sorry but divs are not very well supported and you will have to go back to using tables Unfortunately :(

Comment: Yes I did, I used a converter for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have also got two opening html tags -  this should only be done once in the whole document

Comment: thanks, so I have to convert all div's to table and then it should work?

Comment: Yeah, well it will be a good start, html emails are a hell of a job to do - especially for getting to work in Outlook.

You will also need to only have one opening html tag - what I use for them  - http://zurb.com/ink/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of quirks html email has, [check out the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) to get you up to speed.

Here are a few of the issues:

For background images, there are only 2 techniques to that work in all major clients. The [first technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953246/hotmail-not-showing-html-or-css-background/15955279#15955279) only works in the entire email (body tag), the second [uses VML to support Outlook](http://backgrounds.cm/).

For color declarations you have to use the 6-digit hex code ie `color:#FFFFFF;` not `color:white;`, as all other color codes/names are not fully supported.

`float:left;` isn't fully supported, you need to use `align="left"` in a `<td>` element instead.

As mentioned in other answers, you should avoid `<div>`, but also semantic tags like `<h1>` as they are not consistently rendered in all clients. Style text in a `<td>` or in `<font>` tags instead.

Your CSS selectors won't work also.