# Backgroung image to div issue in rediffmail

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am sending campaign to customers in which i have one div with background-image.

This background image is working properly in gmail and yahoo account. but not in rediffmail.

When I inspect element problem is there. Code snippet for that html is

```
background-image: u-rl('http://www.mysite.com/Content/Images/discount_bg.png')
```

where in my actual code there is nothing like '-' as we can see in 'u' and 'rl'

Any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that few email clients do not support background image property. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

http://backgrounds.cm/ this is online tool which might help you to fix this issue.

helpful links:

1. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3920/bulletproof-background-images-and-buttons-email-newsletters
2. [Background-image css inside an html email - Gmail does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015515/background-image-css-inside-an-html-email-gmail-does-not-support)

Hope this helps.