# Gmail removes background-size in my newsletter

Tags: html, css, gmail, newsletter

I have an email newsletter, that contains product pictures of the products, which are promoted via newsletter. I use full size pictures and resize them with:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 201px; height: 240px; background-image: url({{ item1.picture }}); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto;">
```

Gmail strips the

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

tag and the pictures are shown in their full size. Is there any way how to fix this? I don't want to resize each picture on the server side.

Comment: what doctype you are using

Comment: You could try the setting the image as the background of the table rather than using the style attribute as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015515/background-image-css-inside-an-html-email-gmail-does-not-support

Comment: @Anon: None. Maybe it's stupid question, but is it really that important?

Comment: Has anybody found an explanation/solution for this?

Answer (score 35):

I worked around this by using the background css shorthand method. Define the image, repeat, and size all in one line like so:

```
background: url({{ item1.picture }}) no-repeat top / 100% auto;
```

Notice that the size attribute should be defined after the position attribute ('top') and delimited with '/'.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Brilliant.

Comment: THIS IS VERY GOOD! IT WORKS :D

Comment: Chrome still strips the size and keeps only the no-repeat. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Brilliant solution 

Answer (score 0):

Your technique won't work in Outlook. I know it is not in the question, but it is the #2 most popular email cleint. I'd suggest going with a VML/background combination as demonstrated in [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/).

I'm not sure if you will get a 100% resized background image working in html email though. I've only seen tiled or non-tiled implementations. Is there any reason you couldn't just use a normal image tag? Something like this works well cross client:

```
<td>
  <img alt="" src="" width="100%" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was building inside an email a button with the twitter logo like that: 
[image]

So I was using `background-image` to add the Twitter logo and `background-size` to render the retina size of the image.

I tried the full version of `background-*` CSS properties, as well as the shorthand version `background: url() no-repeat 16px center / 24px auto`, Gmail was still striping it.

So my solution is to use the `img` HTML tag instead of `background` property. And it works actually better as `img` tag is more broadly supported among email clients.

```html
<a href="#" style="background-color: #55acee; display: inline-block; padding: 12px 24px;  color: #ffffff;  font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; min-width: 200px; border-radius: 2px; border-bottom-color: #188acf; border-bottom-width: 3px; border-bottom-style: solid;">
  <!-- logo image should be 48x48px -->
  <img src="twitter_logo@2x.png" width="24" height="24" style="vertical-align: bottom; padding-right: 10px;"> 
  Share the good news on Twitter
</a>
```