# css background-size and html email

Tags: css, html-email, background-size

I use the following to crop and center a picture with css (sorry for inline css but this is just to explain my problem)

```
<div style="width: 236px;height: 233px;background-image:url('path-to-picture');background-size:cover;background-position:center center"></div>
```

This works fine on most browsers but I need to reproduce the same in an html email and unfortunately  emails clients don't seem to recognize 'background-size'.

Is there a simple way to crop pictures in an html email?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015515/background-image-css-inside-an-html-email-gmail-does-not-support

Comment: Better solution is use any photo editing software and make specific image for email.

Answer (score 3):

background-size is not supported by a lot of email clients. 
It's highly discouraged. See [Which email clients support CSS3?](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3107/css3-support-in-email-clients/)